# Specific statement every N iterations in Python

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I want to create a loop that for every 12 months, the 'year' variable should increment by 1 until reach the limit. I couldn't make it on my own. This is what I tried (in this case, the ending should be in 2013):

```
years=[]
begin= 2010
for i in range(0,40):
    year= begin
    if ((i % 12 == 0) and (i != 0)):       
        year+=1
        years.append(year)
    else:
        years.append(year)
years
```

The only result that I get is: [2010,  2010,  2010,  2010,  2010,  2010,  2010,  2010,  2010,  2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2010, 2010...]

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: `year = begin` should not be inside the loop. You're going back to 2010 every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do:

I assume that the range is believed to be the number of months here.

```
years = [] # store the years from begin
begin = 2010
count_years = -1
for i in range(0,40,12):  # each 12 months a year - step 12
    count_years +=1  # add one year after each increment
    end  = begin + count_years  # find the end year until last increment
    years.append(end) # append to the list.

print(years)
```

Printing the years will give you:

```
[2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
```

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! In fact, I wanted [2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011...], but it was answered by Barmar in the comments: year = begin should not be inside the loop.